# Circle that moves on the edge of a circle

Tags: c++

As the title describes, I want to make a tiny circle that circulates on the edge of the sector of the another big circle. I have implemented sector of the circle, now only issue here is how to make small circle circulate on the edge of this sector. I have tried various ways, however, none of them was proved to be successful, therefore I plead you to give me some tips of how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give some more details about what you implemented. how didiyou deine a circle. and what does mean "circulate onedge of sector"

Comment: di you want to draw the two circles ? and see one turning... may be you needto use an ihm library.

Comment: Do you have a "rolling without slipping" condition to be satisfied (and enough structure in the image to display the result), or is it enough that the moving circle is positioned correctly?

Comment: @Djordje Anatasovic: then you should really expand your question, it is not clear where the problem is.

Comment: nico, sorry for didn't mentioning it, but I have already solved the issue, many thanks for your effort to help me and all of you guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to consider that, for a circle of radius 1 centered on the origin, every point on the circle can be described as:

```
P = [sin(alpha); cos(alpha)]
```

With `0<=alpha<2*pi`

Now, if you change the radius and the center you will have:

```
P = [(radius * sin(alpha))+x_center; (radius*cos(alpha))+y_center]
```

So, just have a loop for `alpha` going from 0 to 2*pi (or whatever section of circle you need) and use the above equation to calculate the position of the center of the small circle.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a a function that can draw a circle at a given position in cartesian co-ordinates and radius.

Use polar co-ordinates (angle / radius), set the radius to the radius of the big circle minus the small circle. Set the angle to wherever you want to start the circle. Then set a loop up to increment the angle by a given amount. After each increment, clear the screen, draw the big circle. Then convert the polar co-orindates into cartesian, add on the centre of the big circle and draw the small circle. Hold for as long as you want.